# How does firefox achieve rendering PDFs as HTML when their own PDF.js only renders to either canvas or svg?

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg, firefox, pdf.js

It appears firefox uses PDF.js to render a PDF file as HTML when loading it. Using Inspect Element, its clear that the PDF has been converted to HTML. But PDF.js claims it only supports rendering to either canvas or SVG. I would like to include a PDF file into my website in such a way that it feels like an extension of the website (ie, no pages, no borders, just flowing text). PDF.js seams to perfect choice for this, unfortunately when rendering to canvas, it becomes impossible to select the text. And their SVG implementation is incomplete.

So does PDF.js actually support rendering to HTML? If no, how does Firefox do it? And could I use whatever that is to preprocess my PDF files to HTML? If yes, why are there no resources on how to render to HTML?

Comment: pdf.js is converts to canvas. On top of that there's some invisible text to support text selection. The invisible text roughly overlaps the real canvas text. See https://www.sitepoint.com/custom-pdf-rendering/ for more details

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pdfjs/wagvs9Lf/ text selection doesn't work here, its just a canvas. Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: The link from my first comment covers how to do text layers.

Comment: thanks, you're right, I should've read it first